# Multiple security providers in Grails with Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, shibboleth

In Grails with Spring Security, how can I run different spring security plugins for different domains?

For a few methods on a controller I want them to be secured with a normal username/password, which is stored in my database.  For a different domain name though, I want to use another method, which in my case is shibboleth.

For example: If you were to acceces example.com/abc you would be redirected to a user/pass page.  If you were to access the same webapp as sub.example.com/abc you would be led through the shibboleth login flow.

The idea is to support users that create an account and also those authenticating with an existing 3rd party account.

Comment: How is that subdomain being passed along to grails? Is there an apache infront or something else?

Comment: In this case, yes, although it could also just be tomcat configured to listen on multiple aliases.

Answer (score 0):

At the start you can use the filterChain.chainMap to change out the different filters for different urls which will allow to switch between providers, but I'm not sure about is dealing with the subdomains. The [doc for the chainMap](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/16%20Filters.html).